# Llenar varios "SELECT" a partir de otro "SELECT" con AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax, webservice

soy nuevo con AJAX, la verdad ya busque, encontre varios recursos, tutoriales y demas lo que trato de hacer es:

De un primer select, selecciono un dato y deberia aparecer otro SELECT con una lista de mi base de datos por peticion POST, lo intento hacer con AJAX para no recargar la pagina, pero al momento de traerme los datos, se duplica el contenido, ya hice varios intentos y siempre es lo mismo :(.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="formulario">
        <label>Año:</label><br>
        <select name="anio" id="anio">
            <option value="0">SELECCIONA UN AÑO</option>
                <?php
                $resultado = Sistema::obtenerAños();
                foreach ($resultado as $res) {
                    echo "<option value='".$res['anio']."'>".$res['anio']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <select name="marcas" id="marcas" disabled="disabled">
            <option value="0">SELECCIONA UNA MARCA</option>
            
        </select>
    </form>

    <div id="respuesta">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#anio').change(function() {
    var año = $(this).val();

    if (año != 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "sistema_diagramas.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {anio:año},
        }).done(function(r){
            $('#respuesta').html(r);
            $('#marcas').prop("disabled", false);
        })
    }
});
 });

</script>
```

```html
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $año = $_POST['anio'];
    
    echo $año;
}
```

Es este ultimo, que viene siendo el codigo php, lo deje asi para que me mostrara en el div "respuesta" el año que esta obteniendo, si lo muestra, pero el primer select se duplica.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se generaba porque trataba de hacer la consulta a la misma ruta, ya que incluía una ruta de vista, lo que hice fue generar un archivo separado de consulta para el POST y así ya no se duplicaba.